# What is the c++ equivalent to BP's Class Reference?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am converting BP to C++ and the variable in question is a Class Reference;

What is the C++ equivalent?

TSubclassOf? Type* -> StaticClass()?

I know I am overthinking this.

[image]

Comment: Maybe `Type::StaticClass()`?

Comment: Blueprint interprets `UClass*` as a class reference.

Comment: @George Just a pointer of type UClass*? Type*?

Comment: @Max Play Is it common practice to pass APointLight::StaticClass() as a parameter?

Comment: The property type should be a `TSubclassOf` if it must have a class constraint or a `UClass*` if it can be any class.

Comment: Yes. `TSubClassOf` is a wrapper around `UClass*` which allows enforcing a parent, for example you may only assign `AActor` and classes that derieve it like `ACharacter` to a `TSubClassOf<AActor>`. `T::StaticClass` returns a `UClass*` for `T` where `T` is a `UObject`, I.e. `AActor::StaticClass` returns a pointer to the reflected `UClass` of `AActor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivelent would be TSubclassOf however to get a reference to a specific class you would use ClassName::StaticClass() so for example if you wanted a drop down that allowed for all Pawn types but defaulted to MyGameCharacter the code would be:

```
UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, EditAnywhere)
TSubclassOf<APawn> PawnType;

void MyClassConstructor()
{
    PawnType = MyGameCharacter::StaticClass();
}
```